# Cannot migrate a key between redis instances

Tags: redis

https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3689

On a RHEL(RedHat) machine installed Redis 3.0.7 as a deamon: Let's call this "A" .
On a Windows Server 2012 machine installed Redis 3.2.1 as a service: Let's call this "B".

I want to migrate the key of "IdentityRepo" from A to B. In order to achive that I tried to execute the following command on Redis A.

```
migrate <IP of B> 6379 "IdentityRepo" 3 1000 COPY REPLACE
```

The following error occured:

```
(error) ERR Target instance replied with error: ERR DUMP payload version or checksum are wrong
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: try increase the timeout from 1000 ms to some higher value, also do you need the destination db as 3, or the default 0

Comment: I agree with @Tuco. Make this value 15000

Comment: I updated the error text above. I had some network issue. Now fixed that error but came up with the following error:

(error) ERR Target instance replied with error: ERR DUMP payload version or checksum are wrong

It's not about timeout value anyway... I tried 15000 ms too. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding version was changed between these v3.0 to v3.2 due to the addition of quick lists, so `MIGRATE` as well as `DUMP`/`RESTORE` will not work in that scenario.

To work around it, you'll need to read the value from the old database and then write it to the new one using any Redis client.